# Path changer in Admin Dashboard without sql

Tags: php

I'm making an Admin Dashboard for my website and I have two different URL for my website, page for summer and one for winter.
I want keep both without edit or change.

> so in my admin panel i added html button to change the path

I bind this with my button

```
<?php

$old= "/Full"; $new= "/only";

if ( $_POST ) {
    $old= $new;
    header('Location: $old'); } 
else {
    header('Location: $old');
```

but I released it wont work in admin panel.
How I can make like this code for admin panel with saving in code 
only change back when I press opposite button.

Comment: it should be `header("Location: $old")`

Comment: location should be full url but it usually does not matter

Comment: @mickmackusa check the question edit

Comment: @rekobeko if I'm not wrong you are trying to change other url using a button. like if admin click and change to `/only` then  other url include `/only` before remaining url path?

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani yes and when iclick on it change the path for all visitors

Comment: @rekobeko are you using database in your web?