# Replace php code with if statement

Tags: php

i've connected this code with html form button

```
<?php

$old= "/Full"; $new= "/only";

if ( $_POST ) {
    $old= $new;
    header('Location: $old'); } 
else {
    header('Location: $old');
```

> i want to save the inputs without sql some thing like Replacing the
>   code  with save but without database does it possible ?

my old question to understand [Path changer in Admin Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46010621/path-changer-in-admin-dashboard)

Comment: SQL is a type of database. You can't save something to a database if you don't have a database.

Comment: @bugfroggy there's another type of database that like file

Comment: just file with project files ican save in it ?

Comment: like .sql files but doesn't require making db in phpmyadmin

Comment: You don't seem to understand what .sql-files are. You can use files to store data, yes, but you shouldn't use .sql files if they're raw data and not SQL-queries.

Comment: Except you want to write to a file and save on the server,  I don't see another way

Comment: The code snippet and the aim `"save the inputs without sql"` seem totally unrelated and it is not clear what you are actually asking

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: the problem idon't have access to php my admin

Comment: my question is iwant to save code change without sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the conversation in the comments, you could just put it in a `.json` file:

paths.json

```
{
    "oldPath": "/Full",
    "newPath": "/only"
}
```

your-php-file.php

```
<?php

// Decode the JSON into a PHP array
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("paths.json"), true);

// If a POST request was submitted
if ( $_POST ) {
    // Redirect the user to the newPath
    header('Location: ' . $json['newPath']); 
} else {
    // Otherwise redirect them to the old path
    header('Location: ' . $json['oldPath']);
}
```

**`file_get_contents()` MUST be enabled and configured properly in your PHP configuration.**

Comment: if i pressed on button the redirection will be saved till i press the opposite button ?

Comment: so the header will be /only forever

Comment: No. If you go to this PHP page, if a form was submitted (or a POST request in any other way), then you'll get sent to `/only`. Otherwise it will send you to `/Full`.

Comment: read the linked question + iwant when ipress the button change the header forever this is  the index how ican do it ?

Comment: Do you want it to change only for the person who clicked the button, or everyone?

Comment: it's not person  it's dashboard for me when iclick the button the path changes for all visitors

Comment: i don't have access for phpmyadmin to make it so i want another way

Comment: Then you'll have to modify your `json` file's values. You can try modifying the PHP array and then using `json_encode()` on it and writing that string into your JSON file with `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: do you have tuto for it ?

Comment: No, it's pretty simple PHP code and not everything has a tutorial. Just read the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: thank you sir very helpful finally someone understand me <3